# Delphi накопившиеся вопросы с ASM и WinAPI

Tags: delphi, winapi, ассемблер

Доброго времени суток, и с праздником всех!
Предисловие: я начал изучать Delphi  сразу с версии XE3 - 2 года назад, а сейчас перешёл Delphi 7 (самоучка).

Ознакамливаюсь с WinAPI и asm. По ассемблеру у меня возникает больше всего вопросов, т.к. мануалы везде старые и нет ответов на мои вопросы.
Перейду сразу к сути:

1. Каким образом можно узнать ОСь Windows, определить ее точно, 10 или
   8, или вообще 8.1?
2. Как можно занести в переменную boolean ответ true или false, используя asm?
3. Как можно интерпретировать код из переменной? И по возможности как сделать шелл-код из каких либо функций? Для минимализации
   размера выходного файла.
4. Можно ли в осуществлять условия для определенных процессоров типа Intel или AMD? Чтобы код на асме работал конкретно под какой-то из
   этих типов процессора?
5. Как читать переменную типа string, в асме?
6. Есть какие-либо соображения для защиты программы-сервиса в теории, от всяких реверсеров? Пожалуйста не нужно писать «Умный реверсер вскроет как 1 палец об асфальт» - этим уже по горло сыт, начинавшись на сайтах.

Буду благодарен за ответы и перейду сразу к практике. Спасибо Вам, ещё раз с праздником!

Comment: Не пишите несколько вопросов в одном, создайте по отдельному вопросу на каждый

Comment: 6 - можно предоставлять пользователю доступ к веб-сервису, код которого вообще не будет доступен ни в каком виде (там свои тонкости с защитой, но все-таки патчем одного байта такой сервис не сломать).

Answer (score 3):

По-хорошему, данный сервис не предназначен для ответов на кучу, пусть и простых, вопросов. Вы получите лишь краткие ответы. 
Я правильно понимаю, что перешли вы с XE3 на XE7? Я отталкиваюсь в своих ответах от этого.
1. На ассемблере этого делать, на мой взгляд, не стоит. Модуль System.Sysutils содержит переменные Win32Platform, Win32MajorVersion, Win32MinorVersion, Win32BuildNumber, которые содержат все желаемые вами данные, без разницы, в 32 или 64-битном режиме. Обратиться к ним можно и из ассемблера.
Если же речь идёт всё же о старых версиях Delphi, то обращайтесь к [OSVERSIONINFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724834(v=vs.85).aspx), например, так:

```
function GetWindowsVersion: string;
var
  i,j,k:  integer;
  OsVersion: OSVERSIONINFO;
begin
   OsVersion.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf( OSVERSIONINFO );
   GetVersionEx( OsVersion );
   i := OsVersion.dwMajorVersion;
   j := OsVersion.dwMinorVersion;
   k := OsVersion.dwPlatformId;

// дальше проверяете все значения, сравниваете с таблицей по ссылке выше

   case  i of 
    <...>
     6: 
        begin
          if j = 1 then Result := 'Windows 7';
          <...>
        end;
end;
```

2. На PC во всех языках, с которыми я знаком, 0 - FALSE, 1 -TRUE (часто TRUE может быть просто положительным числом, но не стоит отходить от стандарта).
3. Не понял вопроса
4. Конечно. Порой это самый существенный путь к оптимизации вычислений. Рекомендую держать под рукой скачанные мануалы с сайтов Intel и AMD (у меня есть и твердые копии, но не все, плюс электронные чаще удобнее). Не забывайте сделать проверку производителя и версии процессора, прежде чем использовать ту или иную оптимизированную функцию
5. Как последовательность байтов. Различайте двухбайтовые и однобайтовые строки. Для ShortString длина содержится в нулевом байте, AnsiString оканчивается символом #0.
6. На этот вопрос в двух предложениях не ответить. Мы пользуемся платным сервисом (Название приводить не буду из соображений не плодить рекламу).